# How do you print all levels of help in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

If I have code such as this:

```
import argparse

# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', help='foo help')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

# create the parser for the "a" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
parser_a.add_argument('bar', type=int, help='bar help')

# create the parser for the "b" command
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', help='b help')
parser_b.add_argument('--baz', choices='XYZ', help='baz help')


parser.parse_args()
```

Asking for the help in a subparser results in:

```
$ ./test.py a -h
usage: PROG a [-h] bar

positional arguments:
  bar         bar help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

How do I make it show the `--foo` option and the help for it, when asking for the help in a subparser?

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) makes it sound like this cannot be done: "Similarly, when a help message is requested from a subparser, only the help for that particular parser will be printed. The help message will not include parent parser or sibling parser messages."